# How to prevent washing machine discharge from spraying out of drain?

Tags: leak, drain, washing-machine

Since moving into a new house, we've been battling with an issue with our washing machine. We've got it plumbed in beneath a sink (as the previous owners had done) as shown in the image below:

[image: photo of plumbing]

Above this image is the sink. The red box on the right of the image is where the drain from the washing machine enters the drain. Just above that is a black hose which is connected to the sink's overflow. The red box on the right is the problematic bit...

When we use the sink, this arrangement seems fine. Water drains quickly without any leaks. When we use the washing machine, however, we often find that there is water pooled on the floor. Having watched the washing machine during the "drain" part of its cycle, I found that the water was being forced up through the other arm of the "Y" (red box on the right).

As you can see in the image, I've applied some tape around the problematic fixture as temporary fix. Perhaps not surprisingly, this hasn't performed that well. In case it's relevant, the tape is covering a sort of tapered, stepped pipe. The sort that you might push a rubber hose onto.

One other thing I've tried is to detach the offending part from the "Y" and cap off the hole. From my local hardware store, I've purchased a range of "cap ends", but none of them seem to fit. I think I'd measured the wrong part - my measurements say 40mm dia, but both the 40mm or 32mm caps I purchased seem too large.

Finally, worth noting that I've detached the trap / "U" for inspection. It's not blocked or anything.

I'm now backing up a bit and wondering if I'm going about this all wrong. Is there a correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: First of all, it doesn't appear to me that the connection from the washer drain is properly connected to this mess at all.  I don't see what prevents that from falling or being pushed out.  Secondly, why is there an open "Y" here at all?  This is a MESS!

Comment: If the leak is coming from second unused Y section, would replace the double Y with a single Y.

Comment: You don't mention anything about the red box on the left...

Comment: Do you have left and right confused? The open bit looks to be on the left. The very poor washing machine pipe connection on the right.

Comment: that drain should connect to the  stepped pipe.

Comment: This is a *dish*washing machine, yes?

Comment: Washing machines need a 2" stand pipe, ~4' high. For a dishwasher you need a **dishwasher tail piece** (the kind with a little hose barb sticking out) and a hose clamp. And that no one has cut too much of the hose off at the end where you can cut it for different sizes. You say one of them is barbed, but it looks like an odd fitting and it's got too many inlets anyway. New tail piece time....

Comment: You need to check the codes, the trap is no longer permitted in most places, This link explains it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmN88UvZfDI  If you got a warranty with the home fixing this might be covered. As far as the washer you need a 2" stand pipe that goes above the washer. If your drain is to low it will drain water out of the washer as most washers do not have drain shut off valves.

Comment: The drain on the right leaking because there is no clamp or seal just a flex line stuck into a hole + @mazura a washing machine in my jurisdiction requires a2” but I think this is a dishwasher.